# Audio player in facebook

Tags: html, facebook, audio, facebook-opengraph

I remember that it was possible to have an audio / video player *in the Facebook timeline* when sharing a music/video URL. Thus people didn't have to quit their Facebook timeline (no need to go on an external the website) to listen to the song.

I tried to do it with:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta property="og:title" content="Ocean Souvenir" />
<meta property="og:type" content="music.song" />
<meta property="og:audio:type" content="audio/vnd.facebook.bridge" />
<meta property="og:audio" content="http://example.com/mysong.mp3" />
<meta property="og:image" content="http://example.com/mysong.jpg" />
</head>
```

but it appears like this:

[image]

without any player.

Question: **Which meta tags should I put in a HTML page to have a music player in a Facebook post when sharing an URL?**

Comment: Only ways are flash/mp4, embedded as og:video. (All music-related Open Graph stuff is limited to specific Facebook partners.)

Comment: @CBroe which partners? It seems that sharing a soundcloud URL doesn't even create an embedded player in a FB post sadly.

Comment: Can the downvoter help to improve the question?

Comment: Then you’re not sharing the _right_ URL, presumably ... for example https://soundcloud.com/flameemojimusic/i-get-the-bag-feat-migos shows a player just fine.

Comment: @CBroe With mine it doesn't work: https://soundcloud.com/join-leave/nouvelle-collection-ocean-souvenir, do you see it working for you?

Comment: No, that doesn’t work for me either. If this is not due to any settings you made on SC, then I guess you should contact their support to figure this out.

Comment: @CBroe I did, since weeks, but no answer. That's why I'm looking for a general solution with meta tags so that I can share music directly from MP3.  Maybe would there be a trick with og:video?

Comment: If you want to implement this on your own page, yes - but then you would need to get a flash player for your mp3, or convert it to an mp4 video first.

Comment: @CBroe Hum this could be interesting but it's a little bit a hack. Is there really no way to enable og:audio in Facebook? Did you remember where you found it's only allowed for certain big providers?

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/music: _“Facebook is not whitelisting new partners for Facebook Open Graph Music at this time.”_